# How to tell to jquery for put request in waitingline

Tags: jquery

if you typ fast in input#toolText Ajax/jquery can't follow.
How i let Jquery wait with ajax till the previous request is done ?

```
$(function () {
    $("#toolText").keypress(function () {
        var toolTextData = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'JQ/toolResult.php',
            data: {
                q: toolTextData
            },
           /*stuff */
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you very mcuh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the async property. This will make the browser wait for the previous ajax call to finish.

```
$(function () {
    $("#toolText").keypress(function () {
        var toolTextData = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'JQ/toolResult.php',
            async: false,
            data: {
                q: toolTextData
            },
           /*stuff */
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider adding a flag and not process another ajax request until the previous one is done.